# Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process inside boundaries

Tags: random-walk, noise

I have some simulation of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process:

```
tau = 0.5; % time constant of the OU process
sigma = 1; % variance of the OU process
nSteps = 10^4; % number of steps to simulate
dt = 0.001;
%% OU process, see Section 10: bioRxiv_ML_FI_derivation.tex
ksi = normrnd(0,sigma,nSteps,1);
f_down = exp(-dt./tau);
f_up = sqrt(1-exp(-2.*dt./tau));
OU = nan(nSteps,1);
OU(1) = ksi(1);
for iStep =2:nSteps
    OU(iStep) = OU(iStep-1).*f_down+f_up.*ksi(iStep);
end
```

It looks nice: 
[image]

But my problem is that I need some colored noise inside bounds for example from [ -1 to 1].
The only ide I have it is to transform the `OU` as `tanh(OU)`, then a picture looks approximately as I need, but I am afraid it is a cheating solution:
[image] 
So my question is:

**Is there are any well-accepted way to model the autocorrelated noise process, which happens inside a certain bound [-B,+B]?**